# Akka Camel: No consumers available on endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, akka

I am new to `Akka` and am attempting to use the `Camel` component.

I've simplified the code here, but basically I have a `Consumer` actor that consumes from a `JMS` endpoint.

In my integration tests, I do not wish to consume from `JMS`. Instead, I wish to send messages to an endpoint that my consumer reads from.

Therefore, I am attempting this "direct" approach but I get a `No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://myCamelEndpoint]. Exchange[Message: My test message]` exception.

What configuration am I missing here?

```
object TestApp extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  val camel = CamelExtension(system)
  val producer = system.actorOf(Props[MyProducer])
  val consumer = system.actorOf(Props[MyConsumer])

  producer ! "My test message"


}

class MyProducer extends Producer {
  override def endpointUri: String = "direct:myCamelEndpoint"
}

class MyConsumer extends Consumer with ActorLogging{
  override def endpointUri: String = "direct:myCamelEndpoint"

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case event: Any => log.info("Received event {}", event)
  }
}
```

Comment: Use seda instead of direct, as seda behaves more like JMS does.

Comment: Works a charm! If you add that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use seda instead of direct, as seda behaves more like JMS does.